# Unable to access WSO2 Identity server Management console

Tags: wso2, saml, federated-identity, wso2-identity-server

I have setup WSO2 Identity server 5.0.0 on Windows 2012 R2 server.

I changed the primary user store to Active Directory following the instructions from WSO2 Documentation.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+an+Active+Directory+User+Store

Since then i am not able to login into the Identity server Management Console.

I tried to login with the AD admin user as well as the WSO2 admin user, none of them work. Below are the errors from the log.

```
**TID: [0] [IS] [2016-01-05 10:17:22,965]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'wso2\test1[-1234]' at [2016-01-05 10:17:22,965+0000] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-01-05 10:17:35,420]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'test1[-1234]' at [2016-01-05 10:17:35,418+0000] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-01-05 10:17:46,485]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2016-01-05 10:17:46,485+0000] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}**
```

Below is the user-mgt xml file.

http://pastebin.com/zTJ2SJmN

Any help is greatly appreciated ..!!!

Thanks you
Kbasa

Comment: This question might be better suited for superuser or serverfault sites.

Comment: Can you login to APIM Store or APIM Publisher using your ldap user?